# Error import cv2 : ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, numpy

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to use OpenCV module within Jupyter Notebook.

I have a message error when I run:

```
import cv2
```

The message error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-72fbbcfe2587> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I have read a few similar issues from other users on stackoverflow. This issue often comes from a wrong numpy version. I checked and I use numpy 1.9.2:

```
numpy.version.version
Out[22]:'1.9.2'
```

From what I understand from other posts, versions 1.8 and above should be enough. Has anyone any idea of what might be wrong?

For information, my version of Python/Anaconda is

```
print sys.version
2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 15 2015, 14:50:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

Thanks for any help on this matter!

Comment: what's the version of your opencv?

Answer (score 0):

When installing OpenCV on MacOS  I received the note:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
    opencv: 2.4.8-np17py27_2
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
    numpy:  1.10.2-py27_0 --> 1.7.1-py27_2    
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

I received the same ipython error you mentioned. After the usual `conda update anaconda`, I'm now on numpy 1.10.1 and both numpy and cv2 import in my ipython-notebook. Why your session would show the current numpy is unclear to me (things like that might happen after a `conda update numpy`, which could generate inconsistent linkage).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a virtualenv you have opencv installed outside the virtualenv, that was my case, make sure you hace the same version of numpy inside and outside.

You can force pip to install an exact version, for example *1.10.0.post2*, with the command:

```
pip install numpy==1.10.0.post2
```

Run it inside and outside the virtualenv and try importing again.

Answer (score 0):

On El-Capitan OS if you will hit the command

```
pip install -U numpy
```

It is quite possible that it will not upgrade the numpy module. Reason being that El-Capiton is already shipped with some python module (Eg. six) and therefore it won't allow you to delete the older version of those module and replace it with new one (thats what "-U" flag in the above command is trying to do). It won't allow even with root permissions because of System Integrity Protection.

So to overcome this issue I am currently using virtualenv (to install and use virtualenv : [Article](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/05/install-python-virtualenv-virtualenvwrapper-mavericks.html)) and inside my virtualenv, I am hiting the command to install. Everything is working fine for me inside the virtualenv now.

**PS:** You might also receive errors in some other pip packages installation which will try to upgrade the system packages (Eg. when you are installing virtualenvwrapper).
So to install virtualenvwrapper hit pip install command with "--ignore-installed" flag.

```
pip install --ignore-installed package-name-here
```